# Problem with Apparmor

Tags: xubuntu, apparmor

I checked the status of Apparmor, and got this:

```
xubuntu@xubuntu:~$ sudo apparmor_status
apparmor module is loaded.
0 profiles are loaded.
0 profiles are in enforce mode.
0 profiles are in complain mode.
0 processes have profiles defined.
0 processes are in enforce mode.
0 processes are in complain mode.
0 processes are unconfined but have a profile defined.
```

So, I downloaded a profile:

```
 sudo apt-get install apparmor-profiles
```

Then I checked again:

```
xubuntu@xubuntu:~$ sudo apparmor_status
apparmor module is loaded.
0 profiles are loaded.
0 profiles are in enforce mode.
0 profiles are in complain mode.
0 processes have profiles defined.
0 processes are in enforce mode.
0 processes are in complain mode.
0 processes are unconfined but have a profile defined.
```

Then I uninstalled Apparmor:

```
 sudo apt-get remove apparmor
```

Reinstalled:

```
 sudo apt-get install apparmor
```

Checked again:

```
xubuntu@xubuntu:~$ sudo apparmor_status
apparmor module is loaded.
0 profiles are loaded.
0 profiles are in enforce mode.
0 profiles are in complain mode.
0 processes have profiles defined. 
0 processes are in enforce mode.
0 processes are in complain mode.
0 processes are unconfined but have a profile defined.
```

I reloaded:

```
sudo service apparmor reload

xubuntu@xubuntu:~$ sudo apparmor_status
apparmor module is loaded.
0 profiles are loaded.
0 profiles are in enforce mode.
0 profiles are in complain mode.
0 processes have profiles defined.
0 processes are in enforce mode.
0 processes are in complain mode.
0 processes are unconfined but have a profile defined.
```

What is happening here?

Thanks.

RCline7

Comment: Thanks for the edit, lustful-rat. I get in, proper formatting.